# OpenCover not finding solution modules

Tags: nunit, opencover

I'm trying to use OpenCover to produce some code coverage reports for my solution.  I've got it running with assistance from this blog post http://www.allenconway.net/2015/06/using-opencover-and-reportgenerator-to.html, but it's currently not identifying and loading the modules which I want to report on.

Here is what I'm executing:

```
"%~dp0..\packages\OpenCover.4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe" ^
-register:user ^
-target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" ^
-targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"%~dp0..\My.Project_Tests\bin\Debug\My.Project_Tests.dll\" /resultsfile:\"%~dp0My.Project.trx\"" ^
-filter:"+[My.Project*]* -[My.Project_Tests]*" ^
-mergebyhash ^
-skipautoprops ^
-output:"%~dp0\GeneratedReports\WebsiteReport.xml"
```

The output I get:

```
No tests to execute.
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
guide and the -register switch.
```

I've tried changing the filter to include everything:

```
-filter:"+[*]*"
```

This finds and reports on code coverage within the test project, but doesn't manage to identify or report on coverage in any of the referenced projects which I actually want to test (My.Project).

The projects are all being built and .pdb files are present in the bin folder of the test project.

I would like code coverage reports from all projects referenced by my test project.  Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Are your tests doing anything to force the loading of the assemblies? OpenCover is a profile so if it isn't actually loaded it isn't seen. If they are loaded you should references to the assemblies in the output file.

Comment: Hi Shaun, thanks for your assistance.

Yes, I'm fairly sure that they are being loaded.  To confirm I added a new test which simply instantiates an object form an assembly I wish to test...  Still no joy though - It's still just the Test assembly which is being identified...  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: If it is seeing the test assemblies and they are recorded as being in the correct folder (see output file) then I too am at a loss. You could try running DebugView at the same time and see if anything useful gets emitted that may indicate what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I'm an idiot and was running MSTest when I should have been running NUnit console since our tests are all using NUnit.

Posting this just in case it helps someone else out.